# Vectorising density of mixture Gaussian distribution and integrating/plotting in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to write the density of a mixture Gaussian distribution to an arbitrary power, b, in R. Currently, I have two methods that works, but I prefer if I could avoid a for loop.

```
dnorm_mix_tempered_unnorm <- function(x, w, m, s, b) {
  value <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(w)) {value <- value + w[i]*dnorm(x, mean = m[i], sd = s[i])}
  value <- value^(b)
  return(value)
}
```

Alternatively, I can vectorise this to avoid the for loop:

```
dnorm_mix_tempered_unnorm <- function(x, w, m, s, b) {
  return(sum(w*dnorm(x, mean = m, sd = s))^b)
}
```

Both of these give the same result, but the second is more efficient since it is vectorised. But I need to next normalise this so that the density integrates to 1, I do this by using:

```
 dnorm_mix_tempered <- function(x, weights, means, sds, beta) {
  norm_constant <- integrate(function(x) dnorm_mix_tempered_unnorm(x, w = weights, 
                             m = means, s = sds, b = 1/beta), lower = -Inf, 
                             upper = Inf)$value
  value <- dnorm_mix_tempered_unnorm(x, w = weights, m = means, s = sds, b = 1/beta) 
           / norm_constant
  return(value)
}
```

If I define dnorm_mix_tempered_unnorm with for loops, this works with no problem, and I can use curve() to plot the density. But if I define dnorm_mix_tempered_unnorm by using vectorisation, then I get the following error:

```
 Error in integrate(function(x) dnorm_mix_tempered_unnorm(x, w = weights,  : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

Does anyone know what is going on when I am vectorising instead and trying to integrate?

Thanks in advance,
R.

Comment: The functions are different, whilst the second function returns a vector of length one, the first function returns a vector of length equal to the length of vector x. That's important when calling function `integrate()`

Comment: @marc1s ok thanks! so is it impossible to use vectorisation for this probelm them?

Answer (score 0):

A possible option is

```
dnorm_mix_tempered_unnorm <- function(x, w, m, s, b) {
      return(rowSums(mapply(dnorm, mean = m, sd = m, MoreArgs = list(x = x)))^b)
}
```

But I think it is quite similar to your first proposal.

Comment: I've done some benchmarking with both options and your proposal seems faster.